# Any way to see what processes are filtering or reassigning events? And/or can OS do this itself?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, events

I've downloaded the respected utility X-Mouse Button Control, which can translate button events into other events.  Autohotkey is another such application.

I believe my work PC has some utility, either from the hardware vendor or from the firm itself that they're forgetting they install, that is translating middle-mouse button events into Left Windows Logo Key events.

How could I find a list of such event-intercepting/translating utilities currently running?

Is there a registry entry that would translate middle-mouse-button events into Left Windows Logo Key events?

The specific issue I'm interested in is that I have two input devices: a Lenovo SK-8855 USB keyboard, with the Thinkpad key layout and a TrackPoint "mouse" with three buttons, and a Logitech T400 cordless mouse.

With just the default drivers, the Lenovo works perfectly in all respects both as a keyboard and as a three-button mouse.  Specifically, the middle-button causes a middle-button event to be generated and fed to the application with focus--good thing for me as a Unix programmer as the Unix apps I'm using via Windows all use this middle button all the time.

Again with just the default drivers, the Logitech also works perfectly in all respects: the cursor moves smoothly.  Left and right buttons work.  Scroll wheel is fine.  And in fact the middle-button is invariably recognized by the OS... **but treated as if it is a depress of the left Windows Logo Key.**  In other words a click of the middle mouse opens the Start Menu.  Pressing and holding down middle-button then the X key gives me the "quick link menu" just as chording the Left Windows Logo Key with X.

My aim in asking this question is so that I can determine whether 1) something is simply translating this event--knowledge of which would hopefully let me turn it off--or 2) whether the OS is definitely seeing middle-button events and somehow treating them *as if* they were Windows logo key events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotkey has a good keyboard/scan code monitor that you could use just to see what keys it thinks are being pressed. That may only be helpful in combination with enabling/disabling certain combinations--it won't tell you directly if something is being reassigned.

Once installed, run the default script or a new script that has the `#Persistent` keyword, then right click the `H` icon in the tray menu to open, then use the menus to get the key history list. Press keys/buttons for testing, and then use F5 to refresh the key history list.

Also, you may need to put `#InstallMouseHook` and/or `#InstallKeybdHook` in the script.

Windows logo key in AutoHotkey is denoted as `LWin`, `RWin`, or `#` when used in front of a hotkey definition.

Comment: Also, if it turns out that the reassignment is triggering via a key you don't normally use, like RWin perhaps instead of LWin, you could also workaround by using AutoHotkey to reassign RWin back to the middle button.

Comment: Further thought: does the Logitech Setpoint (or other) utility work for the T400? Check what's available. Logitech software works well for assigning  mouse/keyboard buttons and may be causing this and/or able to fix it.

Comment: I installed the Logitech Windows 10 software: 1) their bluetooth utility Unifying and 2) SetPoint.  SetPoint only has the "Tools" tab, with subtabs for things like support, system report, automated checks for new versions, version numbers etc.

Comment: SetPoint has additional tabs what would show up if the mouse was a compatible device that could be configured in SetPoint. So apparently it's not. Did you check if there was other T400 specific software available for download?

Comment: Thx JJ.  The only software Logitech offers for Windows 10 for the T400 is SetPoint and Unifying.  I've installed both, though the mouse was working fine before I did so.  Logitech offers no drivers for Windows 10, perhaps because the generic drivers work perfectly.  (Well except for this one problem, and it doesn't strike me as a driver problem.)

Comment: GREAT, it works.  The hooks were actually #InstallMouseHook and #InstallKeybdHook, which I found instantly thx to your hints.  Indeed, the middle button is generating an LWin key event.  (I suspect the driver is translating it.)  Now I'm debating to either 1) simply let the LWin KEY act as a MButton, and use ctrl+esc for the Start Menu, or 2) us #IfWinActive to only have the LWin::MButton mapping take effect for the apps I need it to.  (I thought of using the Windows registry scancode map to remap the keyboard LWin to RWin, but that mapping also remaps the MButton's LWin event.)

Comment: Sorry couldn't remember the right hook flags earlier without looking them up, I've updated the original post.  This is a really annoying problem you have on your hands, I hope you find a fix for it. If you can't figure out the 'right' way to do it eventually, there are some different pieces of code I know that are out there for AutoHotkey that are supposed to be able to detect which HID you're getting keystrokes from--if something like that worked it would allow you to completely re-map everything correctly, but I've never actually done that myself.

Comment: I'll look again at AutoHotkey for that HID trick.  That could do it.  As a C programmer I'd be happy to code up a solution myself, if HID ID is visible in the event structure.  (I've seen code for a 100-line ctrl-to-cap swapper that would give me all the exact functions etc.)  The solution I have works 100% EXCEPT that hitting WinLogo key over a Unix window will (probably unexpectedly) paste selection and in rare circumstances could be very dangerous.  (E.g., selecting "rm *" in one window then accidently pasting into a terminal.)

Comment: another idea is to disassemble the driver, and simply look for the LWinLogo key sim, then search for references to that value, and just NOP/return that subroutine...  Heck, as a Windows standard driver they've probably released the actual code to some institutions (university?).